# Sum values from an array of key-value pairs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, sum

I have defined a JavaScript variables called `myData` which is a `new Array` like this:

```
var myData = new Array(['2013-01-22', 0], ['2013-01-29', 0], ['2013-02-05', 0],
             ['2013-02-12', 0], ['2013-02-19', 0], ['2013-02-26', 0], 
             ['2013-03-05', 0], ['2013-03-12', 0], ['2013-03-19', 0], 
             ['2013-03-26', 0], ['2013-04-02', 21], ['2013-04-09', 2]);
```

I am wondering if it is possible to sum the number values found in the array (ex. 0+0+21+2+0 and so on) and have probably a variable with the result that I can use outside of the script tag because I have 7 of this kind of arrays corresponding for each of the day in the week. I want to make a comparison afterwards based on that. That is the most preferred method for this kind of actions if is possible?

Comment: Iterate over the array and add the second elements of the inner arrays.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the following

```js
var myData = [['2013-01-22', 0], ['2013-01-29', 1], ['2013-02-05', 21]];

var myTotal = 0;  // Variable to hold your total

for(var i = 0, len = myData.length; i < len; i++) {
    myTotal += myData[i][1];  // Iterate over your first array and then grab the second element add the values up
}

document.write(myTotal); // 22 in this instance
```

Comment: I think you meant `myData[i][1]`. And why use `parseFloat` if the value is already a number anyway?

Comment: it output 24156 instead of like it should 3. I've tested with an "empty value array" and I receive the same output...

Comment: @FelixKling it works with `myData[i][1]` but how I make myTotal available in other script tag?

Comment: Daniel, did you fix the typo that Felix Kling pointed out? Rember to write "myData[i][1]" instead of the wrong version: "myData[1]" in the example.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks have edited, and i guess i was being overprecautius by using parseFloat. Daniela i've tested and it works have a look here - http://jsbin.com/ibajas/1/

Comment: @DanielacostinaVaduva, To make it available to other script tags: Make sure that the variabele is global. This means its declaration (ie. "var mytotal") should occur right after the script tag and not in side any curley braces "{}". Also make sure that its loaded before the other script tags, else the variable wont be initialized.

Answer (score 107):

You could use the `Array.reduce` method:

```js
const myData = [
  ['2013-01-22', 0], ['2013-01-29', 0], ['2013-02-05', 0],
  ['2013-02-12', 0], ['2013-02-19', 0], ['2013-02-26', 0], 
  ['2013-03-05', 0], ['2013-03-12', 0], ['2013-03-19', 0], 
  ['2013-03-26', 0], ['2013-04-02', 21], ['2013-04-09', 2]
];
const sum = myData
  .map( v => v[1] )                                
  .reduce( (sum, current) => sum + current, 0 );
  
console.log(sum);
```

See [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: It should be `prev[1]` I guess. By all means the result won't give `23`.

Comment: @Kooilnc Please be aware that `Array.reduce` is an ECMAscript 5 addition so my not be supported by all browsers - see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce which also includes some code which can be implemented to overcome this

Comment: @VisioN: forgot the initial value, added it. And no, it shouldn't be `prev[1]`
@MarkWalters: yep, but one can use the shim from the MDN-link (see answer)

Comment: With an ES6 arrow function: `var sum = myData.reduce((sum, current) => (sum + current[1]), 0);`

Answer (score 58):

I think the simplest way might be:

```
values.reduce(function(a, b){return a+b;})
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to the general question asked, but the poster had a data structure that would not work with this unfortunately. This is accurately the best way to handle an array of numbers though

Comment: Ensuring they are numbers wouldn't hurt: values.reduce(function(a, b){return +a + +b;})

Comment: @netpoetica `myData.map(function(o) { return o[1]; }).reduce(a, b) { return a + b; })`

Comment: With EC6 this could look like `values.reduce((a + b) => a + b)`

Answer (score 13):

I would use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var myData = new Array(['2013-01-22', 0], ['2013-01-29', 0], ['2013-02-05', 0], ['2013-02-12', 0], ['2013-02-19', 0], ['2013-02-26', 0], ['2013-03-05', 0], ['2013-03-12', 0], ['2013-03-19', 0], ['2013-03-26', 0], ['2013-04-02', 21], ['2013-04-09', 2]);

var sum = myData.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b[1];
}, 0);

$("#result").text(sum);
```

Available on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7A7nE/)

Answer (score 12):

Creating a sum method would work nicely, e.g. you could add the sum function to Array

```
Array.prototype.sum = function(selector) {
    if (typeof selector !== 'function') {
        selector = function(item) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        sum += parseFloat(selector(this[i]));
    }
    return sum;
};
```

then you could do

```
> [1,2,3].sum()
6
```

and in your case

```
> myData.sum(function(item) { return item[1]; });
23
```

Edit: Extending the builtins can be frowned upon because if everyone did it we would get things unexpectedly overriding each other (namespace collisions). you could add the sum function to some module and accept an array as an argument if you like.
that could mean changing the signature to `myModule.sum = function(arr, selector) {` then `this` would become `arr`

Answer (score 8):

Or in ES6

`values.reduce((a, b) => a + b),`

example:

```
[1,2,3].reduce((a, b)=>a+b) // return 6
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to discard the array at the same time as summing, you could do (say, `stack` is the array):

```
var stack = [1,2,3],
    sum = 0;
while(stack.length > 0) { sum += stack.pop() };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native map method for Arrays.
[map Method (Array) (JavaScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679976(v=vs.94).aspx)

```
var myData = new Array(['2013-01-22', 0], ['2013-01-29', 0], ['2013-02-05', 0],
             ['2013-02-12', 0], ['2013-02-19', 0], ['2013-02-26', 0], 
             ['2013-03-05', 0], ['2013-03-12', 0], ['2013-03-19', 0], 
             ['2013-03-26', 0], ['2013-04-02', 21], ['2013-04-09', 2]);
var a = 0;
myData.map( function(aa){ a += aa[1];  return a; });
```

a is your result

Answer (score 1):

where 0 is initial value

```
Array.reduce((currentValue, value) => currentValue +value,0)
```

or

```
Array.reduce((currentValue, value) =>{ return currentValue +value},0)
```

or

```
[1,3,4].reduce(function(currentValue, value) { return currentValue + value},0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript built-in reduce for Arrays is not a standard, but you can use underscore.js:

```
var data = _.range(10);
var sum = _(data).reduce(function(memo, i) {return memo + i});
```

which becomes

```
var sumMyData = _(myData).reduce(function(memo, i) {return memo + i[1]}, 0);
```

for your case. Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gismoranas/pUQa5/) also.

Answer (score 0):

Old way (if you don't now the length of arguments/parameters)

```
 >> function sumla1(){

    result=0
    for(let i=0; i<arguments.length;i++){

        result+=arguments[i];

    }
    return result;
    }
    >> sumla1(45,67,88);
    >> 200
```

ES6 (destructuring of array)

```
>> function sumla2(...x){return x.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)}
>>
>> sumla2(5,5,6,7,8)
>>
>> 31
>>
>> var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];
>> sumla2(...numbers);
>> 54
```