# Vue.js How to calculate totals?

Tags: vue.js

How can I calculate the total amount from an array?

I pass data to the child component as prop, and I am stuck here. When I console log prop, it returns a very complicated object . I tried `this.values.reduce()` function but it does not work.

```
<template>
<tr v-for="value in values"  >
      <th scope="row">{{$index+1}}</th>
      <td>{{value.name}}</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>${{value.total}}</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <td><strong>Total:{{total}}</strong></td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    </tr>
</template>

<script>

export default {



    props: ['values'],

      ready: function() {

    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Works here, please share more code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In case anyone else is in the same situation as me I thought I'd add this answer. I needed to get the values from nested objects then push them to an array before reducing them:

```
total: function(){

  let total = [];

  Object.entries(this.orders).forEach(([key, val]) => {
      total.push(val.price) // the value of the current key.
  });

  return total.reduce(function(total, num){ return total + num }, 0);

}
```

This uses ES7 `.entries` to loop through the object which looked like this:

```
orders = {
    1: {title: 'Google Pixel', price: 3000},      
    2: {title: 'Samsung Galaxy S8', price: 2500},
    3: {title: 'iPhone 7', price: 5000}
  }
```

You can then display the total in your template with:

```
<span> {{total}} </span>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you pushed all the values to an array instead of just summing them like:
`Object.entries(this.orders).forEach(([key, val]) => {
      total+=(val.price) 
  });`?

Comment: hmm good question, I think possibly I was using the array to also populate the cart data so I had itemised billing

Answer (score 5):

```
var payments = new Vue({
            el: "#payments",
            data: {
                payments: [
                    { name: "houseRent", amount: 1000, is_paid: true },
                    { name: "houseRent", amount: 1500, is_paid: true },
                    { name: "houseRent", amount: 1200, is_paid: false },
                    { name: "houseRent", amount: 1070, is_paid: true },
                    { name: "houseRent", amount: 1040, is_paid: false }
                ]
            },
            computed: {
                totalAmount: function () {
                    var sum = 0;
                    this.payments.forEach(e => {
                        sum += e.amount;
                    });
                    return sum
                }
            }
        });`
```

Answer (score 3):

As you proposed, you could use the `Array#reduce` function. [Starting from this example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16057843/1105858), you could adapt it to your needs and only add `value.total` to the sumtotal.

To compute the total of all values, you can use [`computed properties`](https://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html), which will display as `{{ total }}` in your template:

```
<script>

export default {



    props: {
        values: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
        },
    }
    ready: function() {

    },
    computed: {
        total: function() {
            if (!this.values) {
                return 0;
            }

            return this.values.reduce(function (total, value) {
                return total + Number(value.total);
            }, 0);
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

**Note:** This will of course only work, if `value.total` is a unitless number (e.g. `1`, not `'1 USD'`). Otherwise you would need to strip the in the reduce function as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this function returns : 0100200  it should return 300 , besides it gave warning , Error when evaluating expression "function total() {
             return this.values.reduce(function (total, value) {
                 return total + value.total;
             }, 0);
         }": TypeError: this.values.reduce is not a function

Comment: Please read: `This will of course only work, if value.total is a unitless number`. Your values need to be Numbers, otherwise you need to transform them into Numbers. I've added an example.

Comment: Is it possible, that `this.values` is not an Array? Or not defined? You should probably add a default value. I've added an example as well (including prop validation).

Comment: thank you its works .  When i check prop validation it gave warning : Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "values". Expected Array, got String.  i changed prop validation as String then it gave me same warning with Expected String got Array error .. Why is it happening?

Comment: Not sure. What is the actual value of `values` before you pass it into your component?